# Java combine ordered collections

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I have lists with pair of values- name, rank

```
A = [ ('john',4), ('doe',7) .... ]
B = [ ('john',4), ('carmack',2) .....]
...
```

I want to combine the above lists into a single collection where the ranking has been merged i.e

```
Combined = [ ('carmack',2),('john',4),('doe',7) ]
```

In sql terms this is equal to

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT * FROM A
         UNION
      SELECT * FROM B
         UNION
      ....
      ) ORDER BY RANK
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Java, I'm thinking of putting values in a map and sorting the map based on the key.

Comment: Are you looking for a `Set` of `Pair` objects?

Comment: Use a TreeSet, then just add all() of your collections into it.

Comment: Use a `TreeMap` to maintain an orderingscriterium and eliminate doubles. Or a `HashSet` and sort afterwards. How do you determine what value to store in case of two identical keys?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not exactly, the object is much more complex, I just used a simple example

Comment: "sorting the map based on the key"  What's the key in this case?  Is the key the rank?  That's not the way your `Combined` is structured.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel a rank is mapped to a single unique name, it may be duplicated in several lists

Comment: @tieTYT yes, the rank will be the key, it is mapped to a single unique name, it may be duplicated in several lists

Comment: If the value is the same in every list (can you guarantee this?) then you're fine, otherwise you will have a problem with data getting lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `TreeMap`, which allows you to specify a `Comparator` in its instantiation and will keep your elements sorted based on this comparator, or a `TreeSet`, if you wish to exclude duplicates.

Source: [SortedMap Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and have a `Comparator` for your Key-Objects, your elements will allways be sorted.

If you want to combine 2 Maps use [`putAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29)

```
Map<Integer, String> map3 = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

Hint: Integer is comparable!

In your case the `Maps` look probalby like this:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String>
```